# Opencv find colors in set of pictures

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a assignment where I have to detect two red spots and two green spots in a set of images. Problem is, the lighting in the images is not every where the same, so this makes masking a pain since the BGR values are in some images a bit off.

I've also tried to gray scale the image but I'm afraid I'm getting to much background noise. to dilate and erode.

What would you suggest I try?

With kind regards, Schweini

Edit: images

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTSaK.jpg)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deFpi.jpg)

Comment: please post pics. do you know about `cvtColor` and `inRange`? that should have been covered in class.

Comment: I've added two pictures to the original post. Yes I'm aware of cvtColor and inRange. What color do you suggest I should take for this particular images?

Comment: You could try to convert the images from rgb to hsv format. hsv separates the hue of the color from the saturation and brightness, and makes it easier to track specific colors we assiciate with red or green (in the hue channel). You can have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Answer (score 0):

I figured out [LAB color space](https://www.xrite.com/blog/lab-color-space) works fine for both the images

**Code:**

```
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
thresh, th2 = cv2.threshold( lab[:,:,1], 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thresh, th3 = cv2.threshold( lab[:,:,1], 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

In the 3rd and 4th line I am applying threshold to the **a-channel** of the LAB converted image `lab[:,:,1]`. The **a-channel** depicts variations between the colors **red** and **green**. The **b-channel** on the other hand depicts variations between the colors **blue** and **yellow**. *(Refer the axis **a** and **b** in the following diagram)*

[image]

`th2` highlights the red dots

`th3` highlights the green dots

There is a lot of manual tweaking involved if there are other variations. Hope this gets you on the right track. Also LAB color space is independent of devices and easier to get same colors across different media.